# Padding array elements by number multiplier in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dataframe

I have a large 1-Dimensional array full of **string** values and has characteristics like this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['1000.70', '2*8020.80', '2008.97', '6880.10', '10*7230.96', '7778.0'])
```

I want to pad and replace the values containing a number multiplying another number (integer multiplying float/integer) for `N(int)*number(float/int)`.

For example I'd like '2*8020.80' to expand to `[8020.80, 8020.80]` and '10*7230.96' to expand to `[7230.96, 7230.96, 7230.96, 7230.96, 7230.96, 7230.96, 7230.96, 7230.96, 7230.96, 7230.96]`.

The output I would like would be:

```
expanded_arr = np.array(['1000.70', '8020.80', '8020.80', '2008.97', '6880.10', 
'7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', 
'7230.96', '7230.96', '7778.0'])
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

I've attempted `np.tile()` and converting to `pd.DataFrame` by first splitting on the '*' string but all those options force me to go back and forth from df to array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a python list way:

```
arr = ['1000.70', '2*8020.80', '2008.97', '6880.10', '10*7230.96', '7778.0']
temp = []

for x in arr:
    if "*" in x:
        a,b = x.split("*")
        for _ in range(int(a)):
            temp.append(b)
    else:
        temp.append(x)

print(temp)
```

Output:

```
['1000.70', '8020.80', '8020.80', '2008.97', '6880.10', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7230.96', '7778.0']
```

Then you can do:

```
import numpy as np

expanded_arr = np.array(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ruturaj's answer, but making the changes directly in the array using Numpy functions.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['1000.70', '2*8020.80', '2008.97', '6880.10', '10*7230.96', '7778.0'])

for x in range(len(arr)):
    if '*' in arr[x]:
        a, b = arr[x].split('*')
        arr = np.delete(arr, x, axis = 0) # Deletes the current element in the array
        arr = np.insert(arr, x, int(a)*(b, )) # Adds the new elements in the array
print(arr)
```

Output;

```
['1000.70' '8020.80' '8020.80' '2008.97' '6880.10' '7230.96' '7230.96'
 '7230.96' '7230.96' '7230.96' '7230.96' '7230.96' '7230.96' '7230.96'
 '7230.96' '7778.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = []
for string in list(arr):
    if "*" in string:
        to_be_duplicated = string[string.find("*")+1:]
        multiple         = int(string[:string.find("*")])
        while multiple>0:
            r.append(to_be_duplicated)
            multiple = multiple-1

    else:
        r.append(string)
```